# jQuery slideToggle and div in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm having issues with jQuery's slideToggle and a div in IE.  My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle_container").hide();

        $("span.trigger").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">
div#prog { width:250px; background:url('http://imgur.com/ozduu.gif') repeat-y; position:relative; margin:0 auto;}
div#prog img { margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
div#prog_mid { width: 208px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0 20px;}

img#prog_bottom { position:absolute; bottom:0;}


span.trigger { width: 100%;}
.toggle_container { margin:0 0 5px; padding:0; background:transparent; overflow:hidden; width:100%; clear:both;}
.toggle_container .block { padding: 5px; }

.block ul { list-style:none; padding-left:5px; padding-top:0; margin-top:0;}
.block ul li a { color:#169494; width:100%; display:block; text-decoration:none;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="prog">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/po7R1.gif"/>
    <div id="prog_mid">
        <h1>Phase 1</h1>
        <img id="prog_dots" src="http://imgur.com/anDNd.gif"/>
            <span class="trigger"><a href="#">CLICK HERE</a></span>
            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div class="block">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">list item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <img id="prog_bottom" src="http://imgur.com/r3fcf.gif" />
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a div that looks like a box with a slight gradient to it.  In that div I want to show/hide a list.  I have an image as the top border, another one as the bottom border, and a repeated one as the background.  The list works fine in Firefox and Safari, but when it comes to IE things get messy.

In Firefox or Safari, the div expands/contracts and looks like how it's supposed to. In IE the bottom image appears in the position where it would be if the list is in it's open state, even when it's closed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Am I going about making this box the right way?

[Demo Page →](http://jsbin.com/ugaza)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention which version.  It's messing up in IE7.  Thank you, SolutionYogi for making the page available online.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your use of position: absolute for the bottom edge image, which IE7 seems to be messing up.

I think the best approach would be to simplify things a bit. For the main background, I would use a 1px high image which repeats vertically, that way you are flexible in the amount of content you can put in here, and you can do away with absolutely positioning the bottom edge image. With this approach, the bottom edge image will just sit at the bottom of the middle content, regardless of whether it is expanded or contracted.

The following should help (I've used red for the background of the middle content in place of the 1px high image to illustrate the fix - you'll need to create the image and put that in in place of the red).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<!--

  Created using http://jsbin.com
  Source can be edited via http://jsbin.com/ugaza/edit

-->

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle_container").hide();

        $("span.trigger").click(function(){
            $(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">

div#prog { width:250px; background: red; margin:0 auto; }
div#prog img { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; display: block; }
div#prog_mid { width: 208px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0 20px; }
div#prog img#prog_dots { margin: 10px 0; }
span.trigger { width: 100%;}
.toggle_container .block { padding: 5px; }
.block ul { list-style:none; padding-left:5px; padding-top:0; margin-top:0;}
.block ul li a { color:#169494; width:100%; display:block; text-decoration:none;}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="prog">
    <img src="http://imgur.com/po7R1.gif"/>
    <div id="prog_mid">
        <h1>Phase 1</h1>
        <span class="trigger"><a href="#">CLICK HERE</a></span>
        <img id="prog_dots" src="http://imgur.com/anDNd.gif"/>

            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div class="block">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">list item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">list item 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
    <img id="prog_bottom" src="http://imgur.com/r3fcf.gif" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```